# Cache evict behavior in JPA2.0

Tags: caching, jpa, jpa-2.0

An application has three entities: the mapped super class person class entity, and the parent and child entities, which are subclasses of person.

The application has created four entity Instances:

1. Person1 is a `Person` entity with a primary key of 50
2. Parent1 is a `Parent` entity with a primary key of 100
3. Child1 is a `Child` entity with a primary key of 400
4. Child2 is a `Child` entity with a primary key of 600

Caching has been enabled in the persistence unit, the persistence provider supports caching, and none of entities have the `Cacheable` annotation applied, or a cacheable XML element in persistence.xml.

The application executes the following code:

```
Cache cache = . . . ; 
cache.evict(Person.class);
Boolean result = cache.contains(Child.class, 400);
```

Assume there is no concurrent activity involving the cache. What objects will remain in cache and what will be the value of result?

As per my understanding, as cache is enable Person1, Parent1, Child1 and Child2 all will be stored in cache. When we call `cache.evict(Person.class)`, objects of `Person` and its subclass i.e. `Parent` and `Child`, will removed from cache so cache will be empty. Hence, the value of cache will be false. Is my understanding correct or I am missing any point?